# How can I export a Jupyter notebook to LaTex with the code line numbers?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, latex

I'm triying to export a Jupyter notebok (that contains a Julia script) to Latex throug File/ Save and export Notebook as.../ LaTex and it works but I would like that the code line numbers also be displayed for future referencing the code. Is there a way to do that?

or its possible to modify the exported .tex file to achive the propper display of code line numbers?

Comment: Are you asking to display the code nicely in LaTeX? You could use the [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. Obviously, if you export with line numbers, it won't compile anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In the file exported from Jupyter Notebook Find the following line:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
```

After this line add the command:

```
\fvset{numbers=left, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, firstnumber=1}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you,  it doesn´t look so nice, but it's functional